# Binding to logic involving two properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

In my wpf application I sometimes find myself wanting to bind to the result of a logical expression involving two properties. Say for example I have a class like this:

```
class A {
    public bool A { get; set;}
    public bool B { get; set;}
}
```

In my xaml I want to bind to something that depends on a logical expression involving A and B (for example the result of A && B). I realize I could create a property C, in which I store the result of this operation and then bind to that property, but it feels like the wrong way to do it.

Is there some other way to do this that is recommended? Have not been able to find the answer to this.

Comment: Hi, AFAIK you must create a property C for that. I can't imagine another way.

Comment: Use a `MultiBinding` with a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and have the converter perform your logical operation on the two input binding values? msdn documentation shows an example which you can adapt to perform your required operation and return the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I realize I could create a property C, in which I store the result of this operation and then bind to that property, but it feels like the wrong way to do it.

There are two main ways that you can achieve what you want, but neither of them are wrong. The `PropertyC` method is probably better in some situations, particularly when your *logical expressions* are more complicated. It's definitely simpler to implement and if it is your view model, then it can also be tested.

However, the other way to do it is to use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in conjunction with a [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as @Viv mentioned in their comment. Here's an example from the linked `MultiBinding` class page on MSDN:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBox2" DataContext="{StaticResource NameListData}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="FormatLastFirst">
            <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
            <Binding Path="LastName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```